# How do I get PowerShell to visualise the user home path as ~\?

Tags: powershell-6.0

In my PowerShell terminal, I can use `~` as shorthand for my user account home directory.

If I change location to somewhere under this path, on my desktop I get the following:

```
C:\Users\Paul> cd ~\source
C:\Users\Paul\source>
```

However, on my Surface, I get a slightly different result:

```
C:\Users\Paul> cd ~\source
~\source>
```

I like the shorter path in the second example, but I have no idea what the difference is between these two configurations.

Is there a setting someplace I need to enable on my desktop to get the shorter paths?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725888/windows-powershell-changing-the-command-prompt

Comment: I've checked my profile script on these machines and they are identical, both importing the posh-git module and nothing more.